# magento - accessing $_SESSION

Tags: php, magento, session

I have magento installed in a subdirectory /store

/  Main website
/store Shop website

If I set a $_SESSION item in /, I can't access it within /store. I've print_r'd $_SESSION in /store and it has all the magento session keys there but not the key I've set in /

How can I access the $_SESSION item set in / ?  I thought it would work because it's the same domain/server just a different folder.

Comment: how do you set something in session? Code please.

Comment: just this in the main webite's index.php file basically:  $_SESSION['quote'] = $price

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all don't edit the index file. Use an event for adding something to the session.

`controller_action_predispatch` is dispatched before every Magento action for example. But you can use others also.

Second.
Don't use `$_SESSSiON` var.
Add something to the session like this:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('key_here', 'value_here');
```

To read it from the session do this:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('key_here');
```

or if you want to retrieve the value and remove it from the session do this:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('key_here', true);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry you have misunderstood me i think. I'm not editing MAgento's index.php, I'm working in the main directory's index.php. Magento is within a subdirectory. The root directory is just normal PHP files

Comment: Anyway...you should follow the standard way of setting session values for magento. That way you are sure that you can read them. You can include in your index file the `Mage.php` file then call `Mage::app()` then add values to the session just like I suggested.

Comment: yeah.. though the main website is its own application.. i just wanted to hook into that from Magento to read the session from the main website (Magento is only a small part of the whole site). Seemed strange that I couldnt pick up the session from the root folder, its like Magento is overwritting it or something.

Comment: Maybe this explains why your approach does not work. http://alanstorm.com/magento_sessions_early